# Trouble using session storeage to show message after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to use session storage to show a message once a form has been submitted. I have it working to a point, but wanted to know if there is a better to optimise this code? Thanks in advance

Caling the function here;

```
  $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?account=pending");
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.reset__button').removeClass('active');
    $('.create_account_b2b').hide();
    $('.login_account_b2b').show();
    $('.reset_password_b2b').hide();
    handleMessage();
  });
```

Here is the function that with session storage

```
  function handleMessage(){
    var create = sessionStorage.getItem('account');

    if(create == '1'){
     // display the under review message here
       sessionStorage.setItem('account','0');
       $('p.login-message').text('Your Account Is Currently Under Review and we will be in touch within 2 weeks');
    } else {
     // toggle back to orginal message
      sessionStorage.setItem('account','1');
      $('p.login-message').text('Please login to access our Wholesale store');
     }
   }
   handleMessage();
```

Comment: What is the expected scenario. You are simply toggling the session value on the handleMessage.

Comment: Hi @ZamAbdulVahid - yes, basically i want the default message to be 'Login' if a customer already has an account, but when a new account is created and the form is submitted, the page automaticlly refreshes 'Shopify form behaviour' so i want to use session storage to toggle a different message based on the session storage value.

Comment: Ok whats the issue you are facing now. In which an all instances you are calling handleMessage()?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid - the problem is when i reload the page manually, the message will change on each refresh as the session value toggles from 0 and 1. I only want the 'Pending account messge' which is set to 1 once, and clear storgae when the page is refreshed so that the message by default is the login message. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the Jquery part togerther.

```
$('.create_account_b2b, .reset_password_b2b').hide();
```

And

```
function handleMessage(action = 'login'){
   // Default Message
   $('p.login-message').text('Please login to access our Wholesale store');

   if(action == 'create') {
       $('p.login-message').text('Your Account Is Currently Under Review and we will be in touch within 2 weeks');
   }
}
```

Now that we have added a default parameter string as `login`, on your page refresh you would see the login message.

Call the `handleMessage` function in your form submission by passing the parameter as

```
handleMessage('create')
```

Comment: Thanks Zam, like the solution, the only issue is that shopify forces a reloads on all form submissions so the message changes for a short while, until the page reloads, then the 'login' message and not the 'under review' message shows, that is why i had to use sessionStorage so i could toggle an output message once the form has been received.

Comment: On create submit your page reload, what message are you trying to fit in. Login right?

Comment: Once the #submit is clicked, the create account form is submitted, the message that should show should be ''Your Account Is Currently Under Review and we will be in touch within 2 weeks', but the default message on the login page should be 'Please login to access our Wholesale store', until a create customer form is submitted again, then the default message needs to be replaced by 'Under review'